# Keep the check in checkbox on page reload

Tags: php, checkbox, checked

I have the form:

```
foreach($array as $c){
        echo '<tr><td>';
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="'.$c.'"';

            if(isset($_POST['check'])){
                echo 'checked="checked"';   
            }

            echo '>';
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
```

I want to keep the check mark in the same checkbox on page reload(in case an error occured).The problem is that this script checks all checkboxes , instead of checking only the one that have been checked previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting an array of checkboxes and only testing if the array was set.
Change your check to this to test if an actual value was posted :

```
        if(isset($_POST['check']) && in_array($c, $_POST['check'])){
            echo 'checked="checked"';   
        }
```

Comment: oh... it worked....i was trying with $_POST['check'] == $c but didn't worked....probably because it's an array